# Case-insensitive comparison of two lists

Tags: python, list, comparison

I have 2 lists. The first is `list_A = ['Sasi', 'Babu', 'kuttapppan', 'mathayi']` and my second list is `list_B = ['Raman', 'Kesavan', 'sasi', 'unni', 'Kuttappan']`.

I want to compare these two lists and identify the values which are duplicated in the second list regardless of if it starts with a capital letter or a lowercase letter. I've tried the following method:

```
if not [name for name in list_A if name in list_B]:
     print name
```

But it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#Might be better if we are dealing with huge lists.  

list_A = ['Sasi', 'Babu', 'kuttapppan', 'mathayi']
list_B = ['Raman', 'Kesavan', 'sasi', 'unni', 'Kuttappan'].

d = [x.lower() for x in list_A] # make dict of list with less elements  
for m in list_B:  # search against bigger list  
    if m.lower() in d: print(m)
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually you can make this in just one list comprehansion:

```
list_A = ['Sasi', 'Babu', 'kuttappan', 'mathayi']
list_B = ['Raman', 'Kesavan', 'sasi', 'unni', 'Kuttappan', 'SaSi']

duplicated = [b for b in list_B if b.lower() in (a.lower() for a in list_A)]
print(duplicated)
```

This way it returns the original values while comparing the lowercased. Using sets will return the lowercased values and will delete all duplicated values in list_B.

Comment: First problem: are you sure that 'Sasi' in list_a refers to the same 'sasi' in list_b?  
Second problem: what if you know two friends named 'Sasi'?  
  
The name is not an unique identifier.

Answer (score 3):

Try using sets.  The difference set operation will return unique elements to set abc in the following example.  Common elements can be obtained using the intersection set operation

```
abc = [i.lower() for i in ["a","b","c"]]
bcd = [i.lower() for i in ["b","c","d"]]

print set(abc).difference(set(bcd)) 
print set(abc).intersection(set(bcd))
```

Answer (score 2):

First, convert each element in each `list` to lowercase with `lower()`. Then, the easiest way to compare duplicates is with `set` operations. You can combine these steps with a `set` comprehension:

```
list_A = ['Sasi', 'Babu', 'kuttapppan', 'mathayi']
list_B = ['Raman', 'Kesavan', 'sasi', 'unni', 'Kuttappan']
list_A = {item.lower() for item in list_A}
list_B = {item.lower() for item in list_B}
```

Then use intersection of `set`s:

```
copies = list_A & list_B
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, that is easier for beginners:

```
list_A = ['Sasi', 'Babu', 'kuttapppan', 'mathayi']
list_B = ['Raman', 'Kesavan', 'sasi', 'unni', 'Kuttappan']

for i in range(len(list_A)):
    if str(list_A[i][0]).lower() in str(list_B).lower():
        print(list_B[i] + " is duplicate.")
```